# IndexOf(elem) is always returning -1 even when element is included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a list in the format below (origPlan) and count the quantity of each item in the list and then translate that into a final result which will look like this:

```
finalPlan =[{"first":2},{"second":2}]
```

My logic is below however in my if statement it is always returning -1 and I am executing my else statement each time, what am I missing? Is there an alternative to the indexOf function that would return -1 if the element is not included? I think I may not be accessing the items in finalPlan properly but I am unsure how to proceed.

```
var origPlan = {"first","second","first","second"}
var finalPlan = [];

//loop through each element of my array 
for(var i =0; i<origPlan.length; i++){

  //check to see if the element has been added to my new array already
  if(finalPlan.indexOf(origPlan[i]) == -1){

  //if not, lets add it here with quantity of 1 
   finalPlan.push({
      variantId: origPlan[i],
      quantity: 1
     });
  }

  //other wise I will increase quantity here: logic not included for simplicity
  else{console.log("duplicated");}
}
```

Comment: `origPlan` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, `{} != {}`, because theirs references are different. To a person, they might be the same object, but internally they reference to different one.

You might want to use some of Array functions, like `find`, `map`, `filter`.

For this example best would be to utilise, `Array.reduce`

```js
var origPlan = ["first", "second", "first", "second"]
var finalPlan = origPlan.reduce((acc, element) => {
    if(acc[element]){
        acc[element]++
    }else{
        acc[element] = 1
    }
    return acc
}, {})
console.log(finalPlan)
```

Comment: exactly what i was trying to accomplish.  That makes sense to me.  Thank you for explaining the problem in my logic.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `findIndex` function and check the key of every object.

*Assuming you have only one key per object in `finalPlan`*

```
finalPlan.findIndex((f) => Object.keys(f)[0] === origPlan[i]) != -1
```

**Important:** you need to check your logic/conditions.

**This was the fix I did in your approach:**

```
finalPlan.findIndex((f) => Object.keys(f)[0] === origPlan[i]) === -1
                                                              ^
```

```js
var origPlan = [
  "first",
  "second",
  "third",
  "fourth"
]

var finalPlan =[{"first":2},{"second":2}]

//loop through each element of my array 
for (var i = 0; i < origPlan.length; i++) {

  //check to see if the element has been added to my new array already
  if (finalPlan.findIndex((f) => Object.keys(f)[0] === origPlan[i]) === -1) {

    //if not, lets add it here with quantity of 1 
    finalPlan.push({
      variantId: origPlan[i],
      quantity: 1
    });
  }

  //other wise I will increase quantity here: logic not included for simplicity
  else {
    console.log("duplicated");
  }
}

console.log(finalPlan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the `if` loop is not quite correct. Since your array finalPlan is an array of complex objects unlike origPlan which is an array of strings, your comparison would always fail and return -1. Try the following if condition instead:

```js
var origPlan = ["first","second","first","second"]
var finalPlan = [];

//loop through each element of my array 
for(var i =0; i<origPlan.length; i++){

  //check to see if the element has been added to my new array already
  if (!finalPlan.some(e => e.variantId === origPlan[i])) {

  //if not, lets add it here with quantity of 1 
   finalPlan.push({
      variantId: origPlan[i],
      quantity: 1
     });
  }

  //other wise I will increase quantity here: logic not included for simplicity
  else{
    console.log('duplicated');
   }
}
```